# FOSUser Bundle Login section on a Registration Page

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

On the registration page (as well as all the other pages), I would like to have the login section on the page..

the way i do it is;

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block login %}
{% render "FOSUserBundle:Security:login" %}
{%  endblock %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

which displays everything correctly.. When I log in successfully, it logs in and go to the correct page. However, when i enter my password wrong, instead of displaying the error messages, on the same page, it forwards to the /login page. How can i prevent this to happen and display the error messages on the current page.

-login.html.twig;

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<div id="HeaderLogin">
    <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

        <div id="HeaderLoginEmail">
            <input type="text" id="username" class="txtHeaderLogin" placeholder="Email" name="_username" required="required" /><br />
            <a class="Blue" href="/profile/change-password">Forgot Email?</a>
        </div>

        <div id="HeaderLoginPassword">
            <input class="txtHeaderLogin" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" /><br />
            <a class="Blue" href="/profile/change-password"> Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>

        <div id="HeaderLoginButton">
            <input type="submit" class="btnHeaderLogin" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. When you submit your login form the login action is called. After processing your request it redirects you to the login route which is different from your route.

It's a know issue https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/399 and was already asked here [FOSUserBundle: embedding the login form and choosing its template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040512/fosuserbundle-embedding-the-login-form-and-choosing-its-template)

But actually it is not hard to create your own login check.

Comment: someone recommended this  <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.uri }}" /> but it doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: If you want this kind of customization then make your own register/login action and template. If you need help on this ask another question (As a hint, you can use FOSUserbundle UserManager)