# Symfony2 fos login, register and forgot password in one view

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I need to apply a purchased template to our dashboard. In this template, the **login**, **register** and **forgot password** forms are all under the same view, and switching between them using simple JQuery.

I have been looking for a nice, not-too-flashy way of combining all three forms into one, but I came up empty.

My standing options (as I see them), and why I don't like any of them:

1. Take the views from the fos bundle, copy them to `/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/`, remove the `{% extend %}` part and `{% include %}` them in my own login view. **Reason for dislike:** to me this looks a little like a quick-n-dirty fix - "that part's not working? Let's break it off!" :)
2. Extend the fos bundle, accept an extra parameter in the `LoginAction` and `RegisterAction`, use `{% render %}` with parameters in my own login view. **Reason for dislike:** extending a whole bundle and modifying two different controllers just to change the way it renders feels like bad MVC.
3. XHR load everything. **Reason for dislike:** this approach makes sense when using inner pages, but for pages that reload anyway it just doesn't make sense.

**TL;DR version:** I'm looking for a non-hack way of including the login, register and forgot password form in one page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do solution #1, and I ain't feeling bad. Overriding the templates is probably the cleanest way to do this imo

Comment: This was also what I thought of implementing, but then I realized that I would need to have two views which hold the same form - once for the /login and then again for the /register (and maybe even a third time for /request!), or worse - have one redirect to the other..
This makes no sense to me. I'm almost certain there's a better solution that I'm missing....

Comment: Solution No 2 is much better approach because it has guarantee to work. I doubt on no. 1 approach that it will work because if you load /login then register template form element wont be available and when you go for /register login templates form elements wont work. So In my opinion Solution No 2 is the good and best approach to do this.

Comment: I prefer a modified version 2.  Instead of extending login and register, you could add your own controller that will load and display all 3 forms.  I think its appropriate to modify/add a controller since you will not use it in the standard way.  I think #1 will have problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution with which I am comfortable with for my current project. The advantages and disadvantages of the proposed solution upfront:

Advantages:

- few LOC to implement
- FOSUserBundle update proof (does not override the view scripts*)

Disadvantages:

- performance overhead due to subrequests
- only forms can be displayed, form submission (and subsequently error handling upon submission) will always go to the pages provided by FOSUserBundle
- still feels like a quick-n-dirty fix, but better than other options

* only needs to override the layout.html.twig file

---

With that being said, here is what I have done:

1. **Render the form in your template**
   Use [embedded controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers) to render the forms you need:

   ```
   <div>
       <h2>Login</h2>
       {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login', { embeddedForm: true})) }}
   </div>
   <div>
       <h2>Reset</h2>
       {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Resetting:request', { embeddedForm: true})) }}
   </div>
   ```
2. **Override FOSUserBundle layout**
   As I use the routes provided by the bundle, I had to [override the FOSUserBundle layout template file](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md#example-overriding-the-default-layouthtmltwig) to extend the standard layout of my application. As the overriden FOSUserBundle layout file extends the main applications layout file the layout would be repeated for each call `{{ render ... }}`. To prevent that, we need to dynamically disarm the extended layout file. Here is what the overriden layout file looks like:

   ```
   {# app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig #}
   {% if app.request.get('embeddedForm') %}
       {% set layout = 'AcmeBundle::layout-content.html.twig' %}
   {% else %}
       {% set layout = 'AcmeBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
   {%  endif %}
   {% extends layout %}

   {% block content %}
       {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
   {% endblock %}
   ```
3. **Create the `AcmeBundle::layout-content.html.twig file`**
   This layout should only render the `content` block of the FOSUserBundle view scripts and is such short and simple:

   ```
   {# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/layout-content.html.twig #}
   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
   ```

Now the forms will render nicely with all dependencies (CSRF and so forth). Submitting the form will however take you to the FOSUserBundle actions.

---

Alternative solution:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17234060/1262901) describes how to manually implement the forms and link them to the FOSUserBundle controller.

Comment: What happens if you have an error in your registration form?

Comment: In case of a submitted but invalid form the user will be redirected to the default FOSUserBundle action for the submitted form (e.g. registration) and the validation errors will show there. Hence, the user leaves the integrated page (which may or may not be a drawback).

Comment: Another solution to this problem is to add the login form to the registration layout... them remap the login route to the registration controller (after including the fos routes) like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608458/how-to-customize-fos-userbundle-urls). Still won't get login errors though, but I think it's a faster way.