# how to handle fosuserbundle form integrations in both layout and standalone pages?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I have been working with symfony2 for a while and I use fosuserbundle (which is awesome).  But in each of my webapps, I have had trouble integrating this bundle and never found a satisfying solution :

I'd like to

- integrate the login and signup forms in all my webpages as modals
- while keeping the standalone pages (and the routes of fosuserbundle,  `/login` for instance)

The problem is if I integrate those with render tags such as `{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}`, it works only if I don't extend the user layout in `login.html.twig`.

And if I want to have a nice looking standalone login page too, I have to extend the templates to put my headers, the html tag and so on.

As anyone have been facing with this problem and found an elegant & clean solution ?
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: The login page is just plain html that you can put wherever you want. So just put the code where you want it to be. Your two points in the list are just a continuation of one. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040512/fosuserbundle-embedding-the-login-form-and-choosing-its-template)

Comment: Thanks, indeed I think the simplest way is to integrate the raw form and not render the same template. Thanks for the link !